# Naming Transformations on Spark and Watch them in 'Explain Plan' and 'Spark UI'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark we can name RDDs by `setName` and see them on Spark UI.
Is there any way to do the same when we are using Dataset/DataFrame API?
And can we name transformations?
Can we see this names in Explain Plan and Spark UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataset.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)

sparkSession.sqlContext().cacheTable(tableName)
```

already jira raised

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8480

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20539